# How to import .ops file in Outlook 2007

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2007

I install ORK.exe on my Windows 7 machine to create a copy of my profile so I will have it as a template to push it to new user.

So basically, I ran the *Profile Wizard* to create an .ops file. I saved it in my documents for the moment. Right now, I'm trying to import that file into my Outlook but I just can't figure it out!

My goal is to have a profile template to push to new users when they log in for first time.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

**EDIT:**

I just figured it out. But I have a problem:

When I create my profile, Outlook 2007 on exchange was not in cache mode. So I created my profile with the Profile Wizard with cache mode disabled. I save my outlook.ops in My documents.

Then, I enabled cache mode so when I will import my .ops file, it should be restore as cache mode disabled... But When I do that, cache mode is still checked (which I don't want to)

Am I doing something wrong? I guess so but I just can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out myself.

The only thing to do is to start the setup.exe with the /admin (setup.exe /admin). Then, the OCT (Office Customization Tool) pops up. Do you stuff, set the settings... then, save the .msp file in the UPDATES folders (The CD must be copied on the network)

I copied that msp file to PROPLUS.WW folder. Edited the config.xml and VOILA! Just start the setup.exe from the network and the .msp file configuration will do the trick!